# how would i navigate to a page in buildResults

Tags: flutter, navigation

// how would i navigate to a page in the build results but it only seems to work when making new cards. this is a query search where the user will make the search but navigate to the details page.

```
       final jewellerysearch = [
 "pandora spain ring",
 "pandora puppy charm",
 "pandora bracelet with leafring",

 ];

        @override
          Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {

            return Card( // here is where i would like to navigate to instead of making a stadium border
         color: Colors.red,
         shape: StadiumBorder(),
         child: Center(
           child: Text(query)

     ),
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand correctly, you can use InkWell on your card to make a route link,

```
   final jewellerysearch = [
 "pandora spain ring",
 "pandora puppy charm",
 "pandora bracelet with leafring",

 ];

        @override
          Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {

            return InkWell(
                onTap: (){
                   //you can decline your navigation method here, such as below sample 
                   Navigator.push(
                    context,
                     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
                       );
                      }
            child: Card( // here is where i would like to navigate to instead of making a stadium border
         color: Colors.red,
         shape: StadiumBorder(),
         child: Center(
           child: Text(query)

     ),
        ));
```

Comment: When doing this the page is white. A product name , price and picture is meant to be passed in the navigator but it says they are undefined when I’ve used this before

Comment: You want to navigate to an existent product page or you want to change the page's apperance according to selection? Generally in shop apps doesn't need to make a new page for each product, same layout can be used with diffirent data, or you can carry data between pages with pushname or arguments methods or you can use a database to store your products and fetch them with a future/stream builder or change page with setstate etc. There is too many correct way to do this. But again I am not sure I understand what you want correctly.

Comment: hi sorry how could i change the pages apperance according to the selection

Comment: Basicly you need to call setstate after select new data.You can use a variable for selection and use this variable inside your widgets, when variable value change all widgets will change according to new value after setstate.